# Game does not finish when I get to 100 points for computer

Tags: c++, function, while-loop

It is strange, I coded my pig game here in c++ which once the user or computer reaches 100 he wins. But the problem is if I keep rolling and I go past 100 I don't win unless I hold after I get there. And the computer if it gets close to 100 around 80 to 100 it will just say it wins. I don't understand whats going on here and what the problem is? I did everything right! Or am I missing something?

How can I fix this issue where once I reach 100 rolling or holding on the users end that it just wins and doesn't go past 100 so if I hold at 100+ it tells me I win. How can I go about making it so the computer only wins when it actually gets to 100 or past it automatically?

Comment: *I did everything right!* - Yes, you'll learn to distrust that attitude in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way :

```
            do
            {
               if((humanTotalScore < 100) && (computerTotalScore < 100))
               continuePlay = true;
               else
               continuePlay = false;

                {

                    humanTurn(humanTotalScore);
                    computerTurn(computerTotalScore);
                }


                if(humanTotalScore >= 100)
                {
                    cout << "You won!";
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (computerTotalScore >= 100)   
                {

                    cout << "You lost!";
                    return 0;
                } 
           }
             while(continuePlay == true);
```

and

```
int computerTurn(int& computerTotalScore)
    {
            int currentScore = 0;
            int randomDiceRoll;
            cout << " " << endl;
            cout << "The computer will now make its move" << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            while ((currentScore < 20) && (computerScore != 1)&&computerTotalScore<100)
            {
                    randomDiceRoll = diceRollFunction();
                    if (randomDiceRoll == 1)
                    {
                            cout << "The computer rolled: ";
                            cout << randomDiceRoll;
                            cout << " " << endl;
                            cout << "The computers total score is: " << computerTotalScore;
                            cout << " " << endl;
                            cout << " " << endl;
                            cout << "The computer has rolled a one, it is now your turn." << endl;
                            cout << " " << endl;

                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            currentScore += randomDiceRoll;
                            computerTotalScore += randomDiceRoll;
                            cout << "The computer rolled: ";
                            cout << randomDiceRoll;
                            cout << " " << endl;
                            cout << "The computers total score is: " << computerTotalScore;
                            cout << " " << endl;
                            cout << " " << endl;
                    }
            }
            if(currentScore >= 20)
            {
                    computerTotalScore += computerScore;
                    cout << "The computer has reached a max of 20 points for their turn" << endl;
                    cout << " " << endl;
            }

            return computerTotalScore;
    }
```

changes made :

- The `if` condition was altered due to flaw in logic.
- The `If`   condition,`if((humanTotalScore < 100) && (computerTotalScore < 100))`  was moved into the `do-while` loop. Since it have to be updated each time anyone plays.
- The function `int computerTurn(int& computerTotalScore)` was altered,In some places  `computerScore` was used instead of `computerTotalScore`

Comment: The computer still has the ability to win at 69 points which i dont udnerstand?

Comment: Computer should only win when he reaches 100 or more. But he can win at 69? I can paste the output of this game if you want to see.

Comment: Also the player can still go above 100 and unless i hold it then i win. If i keep rolling it just keeps going.

Comment: Wow that works i see what you did! But the other problem was that if human reaches 100 he just keeps going unless i press hold, Thats the other thing ive been stuck on. Let me update my fixes as well in the code above.

Comment: Thats just my last problem that human doesnt automatically go to You Win! Unless i perss hold when it reaches 100...

Comment: Try it this way...inside `while (rollOrHold == 'r')` give a `if condition` to break if  `humanTotalScore>=100 `

Comment: I put `if(humanTotalScore>=100){break;}` inside and it didnt work 0.o

Comment: Whoa it worked but now its just not letting player make any moves.. But it doesnt say it won.

Comment: Basically it still asks to roll but if i pressi t only computer rolls if i use `if (humanScore>=100)
   {
   break;
   }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4253/discussion-between-mystycs-and-sanjay)

Answer (score 5):

Your test to continue play should be AND not OR.

```
if((humanTotalScore < 100) || (computerTotalScore < 100))
```

should be

```
if((humanTotalScore < 100) && (computerTotalScore < 100))
```

Otherwise both need to be over 100 before it will stop, not just one of them.

I didn't look for any other bugs which may be there, I stopped when I found that one.

Answer (score 4):

Did you notice that your logic that assigns to continuePlay is outside the play loop?

Comment: So it calls this after it makes each move ?

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
if((humanTotalScore < 100) || (computerTotalScore < 100))
```

have

```
if((humanTotalScore <= 100) && (computerTotalScore <= 100))
```